# What do I place as the report id in the PowerBIEmbed when creating a new report?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to use the `PowerBIEmbed` React component to create and design a new report.  Everything works great when I edit an existing report, but when I'm creating a new one (using an embed token generated with `TokenAccessLevel.Create`), I'm getting the following error:

> Report id is required, but it was not found. You must provide an id either as part of embed configuration or as attribute 'powerbi-report-id'.

The id I'm passing in via the configuration is the empty GUID (`"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"`).  I have also tried deleting that property from the configuration.

I have the permissions set to `models.Permissions.All` (which includes `models.Permissions.Create`), so that isn't the issue.

#### Client code

```js
const config = {
  permissions: models.Permissions.All,
  tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
  type: 'report',
  embedURL: generatedURL,
  accessToken: generatedToken,
  viewMode: models.ViewMode.Edit,
};

return (
  <PowerBIEmbed
    embedConfig={config}
    getEmbeddedComponent={report => this.setState({ report })}
  />
);
```

#### Server Code

```cs
var authToken = await PowerBIAuthentication.DoAuthentication(_Config);
using var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(_Config.ApiUrl), authToken);
var dataSets = await client.Datasets.GetDatasetsInGroupAsync(_Config.WorkspaceId, cancellationToken);
var dataSet = dataSets.Value.First(x => x.Name == "AppProtoModel");

var embedTokenParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(TokenAccessLevel.Create, dataSet.Id);
var embedToken = await client.Reports.GenerateTokenForCreateInGroupAsync(
  _Config.WorkspaceId, 
  embedTokenParameters, 
  cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

myDoc.PowerBISettings.EmbedToken = embedToken;
myDoc.PowerBISettings.EmbedUrl = dataSet.CreateReportEmbedURL;

return myDoc;
```

Comment: are you not simply missing `id` in your `config` object?

Comment: What is the ID of a new report?

Comment: did you try the GUID you made? your codeblock doesn't show `id` so wasn't sure how you tried to use it

Comment: or maybe it's checking for the key `id` even if it's undefined? I'm just looking at the docs here and there's an example of that https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Client-React

Comment: Hah!  The report id was being passed into my component, but I wasn't attaching it to the configuration.  Go figure.  Now I have other issues, but I'll figure those out.  Thanks!

Comment: Wait, no, it looks like those issues are still related to the ID.  Passing in the empty GUID causes a request to be made to `/explore/reports/<empty guid>/...` which results in a 401.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, PowerBIEmbed component from [powerbi-client-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/powerbi-client-react) library does not support create mode embedding for Power BI Report and, it can be achieved using [Power BI JS SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/powerbi-client).

Refer below code snippets:

```js
const embedConfiguration: IEmbedConfiguration = {
   permissions: models.Permissions.All,
   tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
   type: "report",
   embedUrl: createReportEmbedURL,
   accessToken: createEmbedToken,
   viewMode: models.ViewMode.Edit,
   datasetId: datasetId, 
};

const report = powerbi.createReport(reportContainer, embedConfiguration);
```

createReportEmbedURL mentioned in above snippet can be generated using [Datasets - Get Dataset API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getdataset).
createEmbedToken mentioned in above snippet can be generated using [Embed Token - Report GenerateTokenForCreateInGroup API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/reports_generatetokenforcreateingroup).

Note: The datasetId passed in the configuration should be the same which is used to generate createReportEmbedURL.

Refer following docs for more information:
[Create and save embedded report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/create-edit-report-embed-view?tabs=embed-for-your-organization#create-a-new-report)

Comment: I actually figured that out, but forgot to address this question.  I forked the package and implemented it myself (the best I could to fit my needs).  Here's the [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-client-react/pull/39).  Microsoft has yet to comment.